# Help in the proof of Horrocks theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm trying understand this proof:

[image]

Obviously, $b_s\in \mathfrak a$, to see this just take $g_1=0$, but I couldn't prove why the others $b_i$ are in $\mathfrak a$. If we do as the author said we had $-b_sa_{d-1}+b_sb_{s-1}\in \mathfrak a$ which doesn't help to prove $b_{s-1}\in \mathfrak a$.

I'm sure it's just a silly thing, I need just a little help here in this elementary abstract algebra doubt.

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: This is from page 847 from Serge Lang, *Algebra*. Not a very readable book :(