# Confusion about two statement of Horrocks Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to understand Horrocks theorem.I have found two statement of Horrocks theorem:

> **Theorem**: If $A$ is local and let $M$ be a finitely presented projective $A[T]$ module.Suppose there is a monic $f \in A[T]$ such that $M_f$ is free over $A_f[T]$ then $M$ is $A[T]$ free.
>
> **Theorem:** Let $(A,m)$ be local ring and let $f$ be a unimodular vector in $A[x]^n$ such that some component has leading coefficient $1$.Then $f$ has unimodular extension property.

Recall that $f \in A^n$ is called unimodular if the ideal generated by components of $f$ is $A$. $f$ has unimodular extension property if there exist a invertible $n \times n$ matrix with entries in $A$ whose first column is given by components of $f$.

> Is there any connection between two theorems above?

Comment: Where did you find the first statement? It is false. For example, take $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ local Noetherian and consider $M=A[T]/(\mathfrak{m}, T)$. Then $M_T=0$, hence free, but $M$ is not $A$-free. Even your notation is misleading. What does one mean by $A_f$, when $f\not\in A$?

Comment: @Mohan: I found the statement [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19584/what-is-the-insight-of-quillens-proof-that-all-projective-modules-over-a-polyno)

Comment: I do not find the statement you make there. Which specific statement do you mean? When you quote, please be precise, since as I mentioned, what you quote is a) wrong, b) meaningless.

Comment: @Mohan: The first statement is from answer $1$ of the above link.The second statement if from Lang's Algebra which can be find                  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727609/help-in-the-proof-of-horrocks-theorem) also.

Comment: The statement assumes $M$ is projective over $A[T]$. It is stated wrong. The correct statement is if $M_f$ is $A_f[T]$ free, then $M$ is $A[T]$ free. ($M$ is projective over $A[T]$, $f$ is monic in $T$).  $A_f$ is meaningless. With this correct statement, your second theorem is an easy corollary of the first.

Comment: @Mohan: Can you please say how does one gets thorem $2$ from theorem $1$? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notion of unimodular extension property is equivalent to the projective module $P=\oplus Re_i/(f_1,\ldots,f_n)R$ being free, where $R$ could be any ring, but in your case, $R=A[T]$ and one of the $f_i$s is monic. Now, when we invert $f_i$, then the unimodular row has a unit as its $i^{th}$  entry and then it is immediate that the set $e_j, j\neq i$ generates $P_f$ freely. So, by the first theorem, $P$ is free.